# How to enter information into a series of forms and display that information?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, sequence

Total novice at programming here looking for some basic understanding.

I am working on a project with several checkbox / dropdown select id's.

ex.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <div class="select">
        <select id>
            <option>-</option>
            <option>2.00</option>
            <option>2.50</option>
            <option>2.75</option>
        </select>
    </div>

<div class="checkboxes">
options:
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="O1">O1
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="O2">O2
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="O3">O3
<br>
</div>

</html>
```

There are about five or six of them in sequence. What I am looking to do (and have no clue how to do it) is make these five selections be sequential (meaning that there is a "Start" button, then you are asked the first question, hit next, asked the second, hit next, etc.. The second to last button is a "Review" where it shows what you answered for each of the questions and on the Review there is a "Submit" button which will do a cogwheel "Submitting..." and then finally submit).

I know how to lay out each of the different select id's (couple examples above), but I've got no clue how to "use" that data, store it, ask for it sequentially, and present inputted information at the end.

I know it's a bit of a headache, but does anyone have any direction they might be able to provide me here?

Thanks so much!

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. Probably you're trying to do something with it on a server somewhere, which means you'll need to write some software there to process it—usually in a language like Python, Ruby, JavaScript, or PHP. Here, you'll need a submit button to send the request anywhere. Try reading [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) as a good starting point.

Comment: "01", "02", "03" should be `<label>`s. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Comment: Store the data in localstorage as you move from one formview to another and retrieve them when you get to the last one (overview). One way of doing it, is to keep 1. a controller object that keeps track of the current state and renders views in the DOM accordingly, 2. form view objects that take care of registering the choices indicated, passing them to 3. a validation object that checks the input into the form and 4. an object that stores the data into localstorage. There are probably also a lot of plugins that you can check out on Google.

Answer (score 0):

While this is quite a broad question (possibly too broad for Stack Overflow), you don't really need anything complex.
All you need to do to is divide your data into logical sections, hide and show those sections as needed and wrap everything in a form element.

I've shown the basic idea below with some simple sample code:

```js
var options = $('.option');
//On page load, hide all options and then show the first one
options.hide().eq(0).show();

$('.move').on('click', function() {
  //Which move button did we click?
  //This allows us to avoid repeating the rest of the below logic in two separate event handlers
  var button = this.getAttribute("id");
  //Which way do we want to move?
  var direction = +1;
  if (button.localeCompare("prev") === 0) {
    direction = -1;
  }
  //Hide the option we're currently viewing
  var currentOption = $('.option:visible');
  currentOption.hide();
  //Figure out which option to show next
  var currentIndex = (options.index(currentOption));
  //Make sure that the index is limited to reasonable values (so we don't try to show options that don't exist)
  var index = Math.min(currentIndex + direction, options.length - 1);
  index = Math.max(index, 0);
  options.eq(index).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="prev" class="move" type="button" value="Prev option" />
<input id="next" class="move" type="button" value="Next option" />
<form>
  <div class="option">
    <p>Description 1</p>
    <select>
      <option>-</option>
      <option>2.00</option>
      <option>2.50</option>
      <option>2.75</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <p>Description 2</p>
    <select>
      <option>-</option>
      <option>5.00</option>
      <option>10.00</option>
      <option>20.00</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <p>Description 3</p>
    <select>
      <option>-</option>
      <option>50.00</option>
      <option>100.00</option>
      <option>200.00</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <p>
    <button>Submit</button>(This submits all the options)
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is a way to create a wizard.  One example that uses jQuery can be found here http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/turn-any-webform-into-a-powerful-wizard-with-jquery-formtowizard-plugin/
You will need to edit your html so that its more like what its looking for...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/formToWizard.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="register.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Step 1</legend>
    <div class="select">
    <select id>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>2.00</option>
        <option>2.50</option>
        <option>2.75</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Step 2</legend>
    <div class="checkboxes">
        options:
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="O1">O1
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="O2">O2
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="O3">O3
        <br>
    </div>
</fieldset>  
<script>
    $('#myForm').formToWizard();
</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

This plugin has lots of options too, so read over the docs...

Then you submit your form using the action/method and then process that form from server side...

Comment: Don't understand the downvote? Happens within seconds of me posting. The question is indeed very broad, looking for wizard and server side processing...